# Django create object ignore constraints (objects manager)

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

The Manager, objects, is ignoring not null. I´m using Python 3.6.8, Django 3.0.5 and Sqlite.

```
class Notificacao(models.Model):
    titulo = models.CharField('Título', max_length=255)
    categoria = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=Categoria.choices)
    descricao = models.TextField('Descrição')
    endereco = models.CharField('Endereço', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    localizacao = models.CharField('Localização', max_length=21)
```

When I´m trying to create an empty object, it's created. But I have required fields.

```
In [1]: from endemias.models import Notificacao

In [2]: Notificacao.objects.create()
Out[2]: <Notificacao: >
```

Comment: Have you run migrations? `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: Of course this should be run after running `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: Sure. The database is created and have no changes detected. Admin interface validates the fields, only in shell its not validated.

Comment: Does this create a new row in your DB?

Comment: Yes! A new record is inserted. This is a integrity error. I don´t know why the `create` doesn´t raise exception.